# What is the name for this sequence?

Tags: probability, markov-chains

I just interested if this sequence is studied or it has a special name. Let $\xi_1,\xi_2,...$ i.i.d random variables with
$$\mathbb{P}\{\xi_i=1\} = p, \mathbb{P}\{\xi_i=-1\} = 1-p$$

And the sequence is
$$\eta_1, \eta_2, \eta_3, ...,$$
where $\eta_j = \xi_j\cdot \xi_{j+1}$

Comment: Reminiscent of the [Ising Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ising_model).

Comment: (An example of) 1-dependent sequence.